# Spring boot Dynamic Query

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a filter in my  webapp, allowing to search by vehicle type, brand, fuel, state and city but all these filters are optional.

How can I do this using repositories.

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Iterable<Veiculo> findBySearch(@RequestParam Long vehicletype, @RequestParam Long brand, 
        @RequestParam Long model, @RequestParam Long year, 
        @RequestParam Long state, @RequestParam Long city) {
    return veiculoService.findBySearch(vehicletype, brand, model, year, state, city);
}
```

**Service class**

```
public Iterable<Vehicle> findBySearch(Long vehicletype, Long brand, Long model, Long year, Long state, Long city) {
    if(vehicletype != null){
        //TODO: filter by vehicletype
    }
    if(brand != null){
        //TODO: filter by brand
    }
    if(model != null){
        //TODO: filter by model
    }

    //OTHER FILTERS
    return //TODO: Return my repository with personal query based on filter
}
```

I haven't implemented anything yet because I don't understand how can I do this filter.

**Vehicle Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_veiculo")
public class Veiculo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "veiculo_opcionais", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "veiculo_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "opcional_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Opcional> opcionais;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "veiculo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<VeiculoImagem> veiculoImagens;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cambio_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_cambio"))
    private Cambio cambio;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "combustivel_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_combustivel"))
    private Combustivel combustivel;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cor_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_cor"))
    private Cor cor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modelo_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_modelo"))
    private Modelo modelo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_usuario"))
    private Usuario usuario;

    @Column(name = "anoFabricacao", nullable = false)
    private int anoFabricacao;

    @Column(name = "anoModelo", nullable = false)
    private int anoModelo;

    @Column(name = "quilometragem", nullable = false)
    private int quilometragem;

    @Column(name = "porta", nullable = false)
    private int porta;

    @Column(name = "valor", nullable = false)
    private double valor;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

The vehicletype and brand it's from another table... I'm portuguese, i've translated the code to english...

When It happen, what i need to do?

Comment: If you're talking about repositories, do you mean the Spring data JPA repositories? If that's the case then I think this question is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015244/is-it-possible-to-build-customized-query-at-run-time-in-spring-boot/39015944#39015944

Comment: a short note you can use `@matrixvariable` too

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the specification API from Spring, which is a wrapper around the criteria API from JPA that allows you to create more dynamic queries.

In your case I assume that you have a `Vehicle` entity that has a field `brand`, `year`, `state`, `city`, ... .

If that's the case, you can write the following specification:

```java
public class VehicleSpecifications {
    public static Specification<Vehicle> withCity(Long city) {
        if (city == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // Specification using Java 8 lambdas
            return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("city"), city);
        }
    }

    // TODO: Implement withModel, withVehicleType, withBrand, ...
}
```

If you have to do a join (for example if you want to retrieve `Vehicle.city.id`) then you can use:

```java
return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.join("city").get("id"), city);
```

Now, in you repository you have to make sure you extend from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, for example:

```java
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Vehicle> {

}
```

By extending from this interface, you'll get access to the [`findAll(Specification spec)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-) method that allows you to execute specifications. If you need to combine multiple specifications (one filter = one specification usually), you can use the [`Specifications`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html) class:

```java
repository.findAll(where(withCity(city))
    .and(withBrand(brand))
    .and(withModel(model))
    .and(withVehicleType(type))
    .and(withYear(year))
    .and(withState(state)));
```

In the code example above I'm using static import for `Specifications.where` and for `VehicleSpecifications.*` to make it look a bit more declarative.

You don't have to write `if()` statements here because we already wrote them in `VehicleSpecifications.withCity()`. As long as you return `null` from these methods they will be ignored by Spring.

Comment: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [vehicletype] on this ManagedType, what i need to do?

Comment: @FelipeA. do you have a field called `vehicletype` on `Vehicle`?

Comment: The vehicletype, brand, city and state its from another table... when it happen, what i need to do?

Comment: @FelipeA. Did you link those entities somehow? From your question it's not clear to me where the vehicletype comes from. But like I said in my answer, if you have to join another table/entity, you use `root.join("veiculoImagens", JoinType.LEFT).get("id")` which in this case would retrieve the `id` property of any `VeiculoImagem` linked to `Veiculo`.

Comment: Sorry man, my fault... I didn't see before this... worked like a charm!!!

Comment: Hello, what should I do if I want to pass a List as a parameter here withCity(Long city), because for example my class has many cities and I the user wants to find more than one in the same query.

Comment: @Jonny Within the specification itself, you loop over your list, do `cb.equal(...)` and collect all of those to an array (`Predicate[]`), then you can use `cb.or(array)`.

Comment: Is there any annotation present that can help to code the Specification class easier ? for example the annotations lombok provides to avoid boilerplate coding

Comment: @g00glen00b Have you full example which you had given ans. Please share if you have